Detect hovering over a widget and its children in Pyimgui
Is there a smart way to detect mouse events over a parent and all its children at once in PyImGui?
Typically, if I hover a window that contains multiple items (child, button, input_text_multiline, text, ...), I have to track everyone either with imgui.is_item_hovered() or imgui.is_window_hovered() to make sure the event is triggered.
This is what I ended up doing:
import imgui

def draw(self):
    
    hovered = []
    
    def check_hover():
        if imgui.is_item_hovered() or imgui.is_window_hovered():
            hovered.append(True)

    # Start a new ImGui window for the console
    with imgui.begin("Console"):
        check_hover()

        # Get the available size for the text editor region
        available_size = imgui.get_content_region_available()

        # Begin a child window for scroll synchronization between the line numbers and text
        with imgui.begin_child("##scrolling_region", available_size.x, available_size.y, 
                                border=False, flags=imgui.WINDOW_NO_BACKGROUND):
            imgui.columns(2)

            # Left column: line numbers
            imgui.set_column_width(0, 25)
            check_hover()

            for i in range(len(self.file_line_numbers)):
                imgui.text(str(i + 1))  # Display the line numbers
                
            # Right column: The multiline text editor
            imgui.next_column()
            text_changed, text_lines = imgui.input_text_multiline(
                "##editor", self.file_content, len(self.file_line_numbers), 
                available_size.x, available_size.y)
            if text_changed: # If the text was changed, update the original list of lines
                self.file_content = text_lines #.splitlines(keepends=True)  # Split back into lines
            check_hover()

        if imgui.button("Load"):
            self.load_file()
        imgui.same_line()
        if imgui.button("Save"):
            self.save_file(self.file_content)
    check_hover()

    
    if any(hovered): # if at least one of the items is hovered
        self.is_hovered = True
        print("console hovered")
    else: 
        self.is_hovered = False

